# Javascript calculator how to allow multiple dots

Tags: javascript, calculator

So basically this project is almost done. But when I was 'testing' it, I found out, that I can't create multiple dots. I know why I can't do that :

```
// if there is any dot, and user want to add another dot, then return
    if(containDot && operand == '.') return;
```

So, the problem is that I have no other idea, how can I block adding multiple dots on **ONE** number and at the same time allow adding it into another numbers with idea for making operations with eval();

Here's link to code:
https://codepen.io/Igor34/pen/LYyoZMR

Comment: You can use a regular expression: `if (/\..*\./.test(input))`

Comment: Why do you need multiple dots? If you keep a list of each entry (numbers separated by operators(, you can make sure that each one has at most 1 dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to split the text into each number and look for a dot only on the last number.

```
const currentOperator = this.currentScreen.textContent.split(/[-+\\/\\*]/).pop();
// if there is any dot, and user want to add another dot, then return
if (currentOperator.includes(".") && operand === ".") return

// LINE BELOW REMOVED
// if(containDot && operand == '.') return;
```

See https://codepen.io/jmendes/pen/XWRwjJm